# TypeScript: relate to own property in type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object:

```
const config = {
  initial: 'foo', // must be key of .states
  states: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {}
  }
}
```

How would I create the type definition such that TypeScript can assert that `config.initial` is a key of `config.states`? E.g.,

```
type Config = {
  initial?: <key of .states>,
  states: {
    [K: string]: Config
  }
}

function createSomething(config: Config) {
  // ...
}

// should NOT compile
createSomething({
  initial: 'fake',
  states: {
    foo: { states: {} },
    bar: { states: {} }
  }
});
```

The idea is I want to have a strongly-typed config object that has properties that are dependent on each other in the `createSomething` function. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the type `Conf` supposed to refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe restriction in function

```
function createSomething<S, K extends keyof S>(c: { initial: K, states: S }): Config

...
// Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
// (property) initial: "a" | "b"
createSomething({ initial: 'c', states: { a: {}, b: {} } });
```